# CHOLMOD supernodal factorization fails when sparse matrix becomes too dense

Tags: c, matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, suitesparse

I am using CHOLMOD in SuiteSparse to factor an `N` by `N` large band-diagonal matrix that is relatively sparse, ie, it contains only a few diagonals that are non-zero. The sparsity of the matrix is set by a covariance length parameter `l`. The larger `l` the greater number of off-diagonal elements that are non-zero.

When `l` becomes large and many elements are non-zero, the supernodal CHOLMOD factorization suddenly begins to fail with the error message that "CHOLMOD warning: matrix not positive definite." From checking the math with a separate Python implementation, I know that the matrix should be positive definite. Moreover, when I change from

```
Common->.supernodal = CHOLMOD_SUPERNODAL;
```

to

```
Common->supernodal = CHOLMOD_SIMPLICIAL;
```

the factorization will then succeed. For the following code example below, the supernodal factorization will succeed as long as `l < 2.5`. If I increase `l >= 3.0`, I get the error that the matrix is not positive definite. Yet, if I then choose CHOMOD_SIMPLICIAL, the factorization will succeed. Can anyone help me identify why CHOLMOD_SUPERNODAL suddenly fails above a certain sparsity/density? Thank you!

```
//file is cov.c
//Compile with $ gcc -Wall -o cov -Icholmod cov.c -lm -lcholmod -lamd -lcolamd -lblas -llapack -lsuitesparseconfig
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "cholmod.h"

#define PI 3.14159265

float k_3_2 (float r, float a, float l, float r0)
{
    return (0.5 + 0.5 * cos(PI * r/r0)) * pow(a, 2.) * (1 + sqrt(3) * r/l) * exp(-sqrt(3) * r/l) ;
}

// function to initialize an array of increasing wavelengths
void linspace (double *wl, int N, double start, double end)
{
    double j; //double index
    double Ndist = (double) N;
    double increment = (end - start)/(Ndist -1.);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        j = (double) i;
    wl[i] = start + j * increment;
    }
}

// create and return a sparse matrix using a wavelength array and parameters
// for a covariance kernel.
cholmod_sparse *create_sparse(double *wl, int N, double a, double l, cholmod_common *c)
{
    double r0 = 6.0 * l; //Beyond r0, all entries will be 0
    //Pairwise calculate all of the r distances
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double r;

    //First loop to determine the number non-zero elements
    int M = 0; //number of non-zero elements
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
        r = fabs(wl[i] - wl[j]);
        if (r < r0) //Is the separation below our cutoff?
            M++;
        }
    }

    /* Initialize a cholmod_triplet matrix, which we will subsequently fill with
     * values. This matrix is NxN sparse with M total non-zero elements. 1 means we
     * want a square and symmetric matrix. */
    cholmod_triplet *T = cholmod_allocate_triplet(N, N, M, 1, CHOLMOD_REAL, c);

    if (T == NULL || T->stype == 0)         /* T must be symmetric */
    {
      cholmod_free_triplet (&T, c) ;
      cholmod_finish (c) ;
      return (0) ;
    }

    //Do the loop again, this time to fill in the matrix
    int * Ti = T->i;
    int * Tj = T->j;
    double * Tx = T->x;
    int k = 0;

    //This time, only fill in the lower entries (and diagonal). 
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
        r = fabs(wl[i] - wl[j]);

            if (r < r0) //If the distance is below our cutoff, initialize
            {
                Ti[k] = i;
                Tj[k] = j;
                Tx[k] = k_3_2(r, a, l, r0);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    T->nnz = k;

    //The conversion will transpose the entries and add to the upper half.
    cholmod_sparse *A = cholmod_triplet_to_sparse(T, k, c);
    cholmod_free_triplet(&T, c);
    return A;

}

int main(void)
{
    //Create a sample array of wavelengths for testing purposes. 
    int N = 3000; 
    double wl[N];
    linspace(wl, N, 5100., 5200.); //initialize with wavelength values

    cholmod_common c ; //c is actually a struct, not a pointer to it.
    cholmod_start (&c) ; // start CHOLMOD
    c.print = 5;

    //c.supernodal = CHOLMOD_SIMPLICIAL;
    c.supernodal = CHOLMOD_SUPERNODAL;

    float l = 2.5;
    cholmod_sparse *A = create_sparse(wl, N, 1.0, l, &c);

    cholmod_factor *L ;
    L = cholmod_analyze (A, &c) ;           

    cholmod_factorize (A, L, &c) ;          
    printf("L->minor = %d\n", (int) L->minor);

    cholmod_dense *b, *x, *r;

    //Create a vector with the same number of rows as A
    b = cholmod_ones (A->nrow, 1, A->xtype, &c) ;   // b = ones(n,1) 
    x = cholmod_solve (CHOLMOD_A, L, b, &c) ;       // solve Ax=b    
    //the reason these are length two is because they can be complex
    double alpha [2] = {1,0}, beta [2] = {0,0} ;        // basic scalars 

    r = cholmod_copy_dense (b, &c) ;            // r = b 
    cholmod_sdmult (A, 0, alpha, beta, x, r, &c) ;      // r = Ax 

    cholmod_print_dense(r, "r", &c); //This should be equal to b

    cholmod_free_sparse(&A, &c); // free all of the variables
    cholmod_free_factor(&L, &c);
    cholmod_free_dense(&b, &c);
    cholmod_free_dense(&x, &c);
    cholmod_free_dense(&r, &c);
    cholmod_finish (&c) ;  // finish CHOLMOD 

    return (0) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing with your code, it looks like you're creating rather ill-conditioned matrices and asking CHOLMOD to deal with them.  When I tell it to do a simplicial factorisation on the cases that fail, I get reciprocal condition numbers (computed using `cholmod_rcond`) around 1e-7.  When `l = 2.5`, I get a reciprocal condition number around `2e-6`.  Note that machine epsilon for a `float` is somewhere around here...

If I replace all the `float`s with `double`s in your declaration of `k_3_2`, it no longer appears to fail.  (I haven't looked at what your matrix has inside of it, so I'm not going to comment further beyond saying that `pow(a, 2.)` is a poor way to square something.)

I don't know why you're getting failure for matrices that are apparently not so poorly-conditioned.  I'm not completely sure of the details of how CHOLMOD's supernodal factorisation is implemented, but I believe it calls out to BLAS's `dpotrf` to do the small dense factorisations and `dsyrk` to deal with the rest of the block.  It's possible that a fast `dpotrf` or `dsyrk` could cause you grief.  Also, CHOLMOD creates nonzeros for some structurally zero elements of the matrix just so that it can use BLAS, and this can throw you off a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Changing float->double on ``k_3_2`` now allows me to go to arbitrarily large ``l`` such that the matrix even becomes dense (although obviously this is not the common use case...). I will be more careful watching rcond.